# How to add new item in menu_local?

Tags: routes, 7

I'm using Drupal commons and I want to add new item next to View link, so I used hook_menu to create this.

```
function manage_child_menu() { 
  $items['node/%node/demo'] = array (
    'title' => 'Demo',
    'page callback' => 'node_page_view',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'manage_child_auction_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );    
  return $items;
}
```

Well, it didn't work at all. Please help

Answer (score 1):

In my case using hook_menu will never work. Then i have to use hook_menu_local_tasks_alter to make it work.
Here is how.

```
function manage_child_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
   if ((arg(0) == 'node' || arg(0) == 'groups') && arg(2) == '') {
   $nid = arg(1);
   $node = node_load($nid);
   if ($node->type == 'project_auction') {
     $link = menu_get_item("node/$nid/demo");
     $link['title'] = 'Auction List';
     $link['weight'] = 10;

     $data['tabs'][0]['output'][] = array(
       '#theme' => 'menu_local_task',
       '#link' => $link,
     );

     $data['tabs'][0]['count'] = $data['tabs']['0']['count'] + 1;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add it in main menu. Then you need to add `'menu' => 'main-menu'` . Or else when you are adding menu, Clear all the cache first and then try to render your desire result.

Comment: Thx for answer but in Commons 3, Main Menu did not contain the item like view, edit and delete. Those items is belong to menu_local_task, so I had to stick with menu_local_task to add new item

Comment: Try this:  `$items['node/%node/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit',
    'page callback' => 'node_page_edit',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'node_access',
    'access arguments' => array('update', 1),
    'weight' => 0,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'context' => MENU_CONTEXT_PAGE | MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE,
    'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
  );`